# Google Maps Marker with Ionic don't work in Android device

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am trying implement a Map with Ionic v1.

At the beginning I was testing it only in the browser and it worked well. Then I tested in an iOS device and it worked well as well.
However when I tested in an Android device, the map was correct but the marker didn't appear.

I show you the code for get the marker, but I don't think it is the problem the code is simple, and it works in the browser with ionic-lab and in an iOS device but not in an Android device.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
    map.setCenter(myLatlng);
    var myLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: "My Location"
    });
});
```

I would really appreciate some help, because I have no idea what I can do for fix it.

**[SOLVED]**

The problem is with:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos)
```

If the Location in the mobile is off it can't work.

Comment: debug using console share the output or errors .

Comment: https://www.joshmorony.com/part-3-advanced-google-maps-integration-with-ionic-and-remote-data/

Comment: Thanks @Edison, it was not the solution to my problem but helps me to solve it!